# Can Qt 5.15 or 5.15.x can be used as open source? Because they say yes and no

Tags: licensing

Qt decided to remove offline installers for open source users. But we can still install Qt 5.15.x LTS with Debug Informations using Online Installer.

However they also say:

> **Starting with Qt 5.15, long term support (LTS) will only be available to commercial customers**. This means open-source users will receive patch-level releases of 5.15 until the next minor release will become available. This means that we will handle Qt 5.15 in the same way as e.g. 5.13 or 5.14 for open source users.

But same guys also say:

> Qt 5.15 is available **now for all our users. For our open source users, it will be supported in the same way as other regular Qt releases until the release of Qt 6.** For commercial customers, Qt 5.15 will be long-term-supported (LTS) for three years with regular bug fix releases beyond the release of Qt 6. 26 May 2020

So, I am very confused. I as an open source user am able to download **Qt 5.15.2** from online installer with Debug Information. But they say its not for open source users.

My question is, If I use Online installer and download Qt 5.15.2 can I use it as an open source? Or I am only allowed to use **Qt 5.14.x** as an Open source user so should I downgrade my app to 5.14.x?

Comment: These statements explain that Qt 5.15.2 is available under an open source license (the same as with 5.14.x), but long-term support isn't available.

Comment: For people who want to see where the quotes come from: https://www.qt.io/blog/qt-5.15-released and https://www.qt.io/blog/qt-offering-changes-2020 (it could have been useful to add the links in the question).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misunderstood the statements from Qt.

Qt 5.15.x is available to both Commercial and Open Source users.

However, after version 6 or 5.16 has been released, only Commercial users will receive further bugfixes on Qt 5.15. If you are an Open Source user and you are inconvenienced by a bug, you must upgrade to the next stable version to get a fix for the bug.

Comment: God sake, Now I got it. You made it clear for me thank you!

Comment: i was under the impression that the commercial shenanigan would only last a year 

Comment: @Fuseteam you are correct